# Change Inactive Tab Bar Colour IOS 7.1

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have searched all over the internet and can't seem to find an answer to changing the inactive tab colours from the standard grey, I am able to set the active but i would like the inactive tabs to be a different colour

i am using storyboards in xcode 5.1.1 with embedded tab bar controllers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For iOS7, use this:

//get embedded tab bar controller

```
  UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

//get tab-bar

```
  UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
```

//get tab-bar item w.r.t their index

```
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
```

//set image for unselected state

```
[tabBarItem3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

//set image for selected state

```
 [tabBarItem3 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Here, you can give required color to your maps.png(for inactive state) and maps_selected.png(for active state).In short, you have to give the required colors to your images(tab-bar icons). Similarly, you have to define images for all tab-items for both states. Do this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your app.

For iOS 6, it is quite short, which is deprecated for iOS7 and later:

```
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps.png"]];
```

Hope this works for u! Happy coding!